# Cut everything behind an object/path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an object A overlapping object B. How can I cut everything behind object A so that B has a bite-mark of A? I want to keep object A as is...

Answer (score 3):

Have Object A above Object B in the Layer Panel

Select Object A and go to Edit> Copy

Select both A and B and go to Window> Pathfinder to open the Pathfinder Panel

Click on Minus Front in the Panel (the second button from the left in the top row)- this will cut Object A out from Object B (and remove Object A)

Go to Edit> Paste in Place to add the copy you made of Object A back to it's original position

Answer (score 3):

Make certain A and B have *different* fill colors....

Select both A and B... `Pathfinder Panel > Merge`

You may then need to use `Object > Ungroup` to separate the two objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Shape Builder for this

1. Draw two overlapping shapes, Select both
2. With the Shape Builder tool, click and drag over the intersection and towards the other side.

Example

[image]